# What is the difference between big and little endian floats?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, endianness

For integer values, it is pretty straightforward the difference in little endian and big endian representation.

But it is not clear for me how a little endian float differs from a big endian float.

And finally, I would like to know which is more commonly used.

Comment: The endianness affects the way the values are represented in memory for _all_ multi-byte types.  Floats are no different than 32-bit integers in this case.

Comment: The 4 bytes are just stored in reverse order.

Comment: What confuses me is that the floating point representation isn't splited in bytes (like an integer). Sign is 1 bit, exponent 8 bits and significand is 23. Reversing the order would just make it harder to access the values.

Comment: André, you're talking about totally different things. byte order is a layer *below* the numeric representation. Integers and floating-point numbers *don't care* about endianness; they're just multi-byte values. Likewise, endianness doesn't care about whether it's an int or a float. It just stores the bytes in a particular order.

Comment: @HansPassant "The 4 bytes are just stored in reverse order. "? How to understand this? Could you please explian that in more detail for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some sources say IEEE754 floats are always stored little-endian but The IEEE754 specification for floating point numbers simply doesn't cover the endianness problem and may vary from machine to machine.
Here is sample code for floating point / byte array conversion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  char *a;
  float f = 3.14159;  // number to start with

  a = (char *)&f;   // point a to f's location

  // print float & byte array as hex
  printf("float: %f\n", f);
  printf("byte array: %hhX:%hhX:%hhX:%hhX\n", \
    a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

  // toggle the sign of f -- using the byte array
  a[3] = ((unsigned int)a[3]) ^ 128;

  //print the numbers again
  printf("float: %f\n", f);
  printf("byte array: %hhX:%hhX:%hhX:%hhX\n", \
    a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

  return 0;
}
```

It's output on a little-indian machine:

float: 3.141590
byte array: D0:F:49:40
float: -3.141590
byte array: D0:F:49:C0

Theoretically, on a big-endian machine the order of bytes would be reversed.

Reference:
http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/

Comment: On a SPARC machine: float: 3.141590, byte array: 40:49:F:D0; float: 3.141560, byte array: 40:49:F:50

Comment: This is exactly how implemented it!

Answer (score 17):

Endianness just is a property of the bytes that make up a value that's composed from multiple bytes. Since a floating point number takes up 4 or 8 bytes endianness tells you in which order to read them. This is *exactly* the same as with integer values.